# How can I use step-by-step code highlights when using reveal.js with asciidoc?

Tags: reveal.js, asciidoctor

I have a working setup with Maven generating a reveal.js presentation from Asciidoc sources with source code highlighting.

This is for example a slide with some Java code in it:

```
== Slide Two

Some sample text

[source,java]
----
public class TestClass {
    public TestClass() {

    }
}
----
```

How can I use the [step-by-step highlighting](https://revealjs.com/code/#step-by-step-highlights) from reveal.js from the Asciidoc source block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `highlight` keyword, separating each step with a pipe (`|`) symbol:

```
[source,java,highlight=1..5|2..4]
----
public class TestClass {
    public TestClass() {

    }
}
----
```

UPDATE: This is now also added to the official documentation: https://docs.asciidoctor.org/reveal.js-converter/latest/converter/syntax/syntax-highlighting/#line-number-highlights